# Многопоточный сервер на Python 3

Tags: python, сервер

На моем сервере выполняются скрипты написанные тоже на python. Я создал html страничку где пользователь вводит информацию, которая отправляется в эти скрипты, и получает результат. Все прекрасно работает. Но работает только в 1 поток, то есть, если первый человек кидает запрос, и в это же время кидает запрос второй человек, то все перестает работать, при этом никакой ошибки не появляется.
Вот код запуска моего сервера. Как это исправить?

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("localhost", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: [Офф. документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer) говорит что можно использовать `ThreadingHTTPServer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с версии 3.7 можно использовать [http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer) вместо HTTPServer

Для более ранних версий нужно [определить класс](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.ThreadingMixIn)

```
class ThreadingHTTPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, http.server.HTTPServer):
    pass
```

Чтоб загрузить все ядра (сложные вычисления) есть ForkingMixIn

Comment: Огромное спасибо! У меня версия 3.7.4, просто заменил HTTPServer на ThreadingHTTPServer. Все прекрасно работает.